# FileVault stuck on decrypting 90%

Tags: macos, encryption, filevault

I couldn't partition my hard drive because FileVault was turned on. I then started decrypting, but it got stuck on 90%. After 4 days at 90%, I can still access my device, but it's laggy and frustrating.

What is the solution to make it continue or at least to revert back without wiping my drive?

I tried `sudo fdesetup disable` and `force restart`, still, nothing is working.

I am using High Sierra MacBook Pro mid-2012.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have programs open or programs running in the background when you wait for it to be decrypted? If you go to System settings -> Security and integrity -> FileVault, does that page give you any indication of the decryption status?